# Is a "wrong" to return anything else besides `this` in a constructor?

Tags: constructors, typescript

Is a "wrong" to return anything else besides `this` in a constructor?

Take this TypeScript Queue sample:

```
class Queue {

    private buffer: string;

    constructor(buffer: string = "") {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    push(n: string): Queue {
        return new Queue(this.get() + n);
    }

    get(): string {
        return this.buffer;
    }

    print() {
        console.log(this.buffer);
    }
}
new Queue().add("1").add("2").add("3").print(); // prints 123
```

Everytime `push` is called, a new `Queue` instance is created.
And in a child class i would like to prepend a suffix in the queue like this.

```
class QueuePrefix extends Queue {
    constructor() {
        super();
        return this.push("q:");
    }
}
new QueuePrefix().add("1").add("2").add("3").print(); // prints q:123
```

However I must return the result from the function push, instead of 'this'.

Is this an acceptable strategy?

Comment: Does it work: to return an object in the constructor?

Comment: @ErikEidt: JavaScript is its own beast. Yes this works. You can return any kind of object you want from a constructor. TypeScript may impose additional restrictions, though.

Comment: You never update the buffer which seems odd. Instead of returning something different from the constructor you could add it to this.buffer. It looks to like you added a new level of wtfness to an already questionable design. It violates POLA. Disclaimer: I am not a script guy. The fact that return is not really a thing in script land, that you are really just pushing more stuff into the same pipeline, has bitten me more than once.

Comment: @MartinMaat this looks like a good answer to me.

Comment: `super` is just a way to refer to the *constructor of the superclass*, it's used like any other method call, you can pass parameters to it. Your Queue constructor already takes a single parameter that lets you set the initial buffer value, so you can just do `super("q:")`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is wrong per se, as long as the returned object is a subtype of the expected type. But returning anything else would certainly violate the principle of least surprise.

In your particular case I don't see why it is necessary though, you could just initialize the buffer in the constructor.